# How to find the probability of a given statement being true?

Tags: probability

A statement with probability $x$ of being true is given. Two independent people (A and B) are brought in to assess the validity of said statement. The probability that A is correct is $p_1$. The probability that B is correct is $p_2$. They both agree that the statement is true. What is the probability that the statement is, in fact, true?

Comment: What is the probability of both people being wrong?

Comment: Hint:  apply Bayes' Theorem.

Comment: Note that in a reality scenario, we want both $A$ and $B$ to be highly correlated with $x$, which typically means that they are also (somewhat) highly correlated with each other, i.e., independence of $A$ and $B$ may not be what one first thinks it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive I may have cracked it.

Let $A_T$: "A says it's true"
$\ \ \ \ \ $ $B_T$: "B says it's true"
$\ \ \ \ \ $ $X_T$: "The statement is true"

$P(X_T|A_T \cap B_T) = \frac{P(A_T \cap B_T|X_T) \times P(X_T)}{P(A_T \cap B_T)} = \frac{P(A_T \cap B_T|X_T) \times P(X_T)}{P(A_T \cap B_T \cap X_T) + P(A_T \cap B_T \cap \overline{X_T})}$

$P(A_T \cap B_T|X_T)^{*_1} = p_1p_2$
$P(A_T \cap B_T \cap X_T) = P(A_T \cap B_T|X_T) \times P(X_T) = p_1p_2x$
$P(A_T \cap B_T \cap \overline{X_T}) = P(A_T \cap B_T|\overline{X_T})^{*_2} \times P(\overline{X_T}) = (1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-x)$

Finally,
$$
P(X_T|A_T \cap B_T) = \frac{p_1p_2x}{p_1p_2x+(1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-x)}
$$

<sub>*1: The probablity of A and B being right

*2: The probablity of A and B being wrong</sub>

Answer (score 1):

What we want to calculate is the conditional probability of the statement beeing true, given A and B saying it is true.
$$
P(\text{the statement is correct}| \text{A and B say it is true})
= \frac{P(\text{A and B say it is true} | \text{the statement is correct})P(\text{the statement is correct})}{P(\text{A and B say it is true})}
= \frac{P(\text{A and B say it is true} | \text{the statement is correct})P(\text{the statement is correct})}{P(\text{A and B say it is true}| \text{the statement is correct})+ P(\text{A and B say it is true}| \text{the statement is not correct})}
$$
Hier is the problem, I don’t see a way to access $P(\text{A and B say it is true}| \text{the statement is not correct})$.

Comment: What if $x$ is definitely true, and $A$'s method of assessment is to roll a die and say "it is false" if they roll a six and  say "it is true" otherwise, and $B$ does the same with an *independent* die roll. It seems that this setup matches the problem description, but you compute a probability $>1$.

Comment: Or suppose that $p_1=1$, i.e. that $A$ is always correct.  Then the answer must be $1$ but you get $\frac x{p_2}$.

Comment: thank you, this is of course a horrible mistake. I think this problem is unsolvable with the given information.

Comment: I think it depends on how one reads the problem.  If you imagine something like "$A$ and $B$ both know the truth but they each  toss a (possible biased) coin to decide whether to tell the truth or to lie.  These coin tosses are independent of each other."  then the problem can be solved.